# Table's indexes got mixed somehow

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA function:

```
Private Function getRowIdentifier(ByRef tbl As ListObject, ByVal tableRowIndex As Long, ByVal delimiter As String) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rowId As String
    
    Set rng = tbl.ListRows(tableRowIndex).Range
    rowId = Join(Array(rng(1, 1).Value, rng(1, 2).Value, rng(1, 3).Value, rng(1, 4).Value, rng(1, 6).Value, rng(1, 7).Value), delimiter)
    getRowIdentifier = rowId
End Function
```

This function takes cells `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `6`, `7` of the table's row that parameters `tbl` and `tableRowIndex` pinpoint. Cells are delimeted by parameter `delimeter` *(in my case I used delimeter `#;#`)* and concatenated in a large string which is then returned. This string has no delimeter at the beginning and the end.

But then I fed a table `tbl` which has rows like shown below to my function `getRowIdentifier()`:

[image]

And my function goes berserk...

When I debug the function on each of these rows last sub-string that `Join()` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)) function concatenates in a string `rowId` is always a boolean instead of a string listed in the column `7` of the row...

This is `rowId` when I feed **1st** row to my function:

```
LU3707-E01#;#Blending_1#;##;##;#Blending#;#True
```

This is `rowId` when I feed **2nd** row to my function:

```
LU3707-E01#;#Screening milling_2#;##;##;#Screening Milling#;#True
```

This is `rowId` when I feed **3rd** row to my function:

```
LU3707-E01#;#Blending_3#;##;##;#Blending#;#True
```

What could be the reason for this?

---

**ADD:**

I found out that if I change the line where `Join()` function is used like this *(I added all the table's columns)*:

```
'rowId = Join(Array(rng(1, 1).Value, rng(1, 2).Value, rng(1, 3).Value, rng(1, 4).Value, rng(1, 6).Value, rng(1, 7).Value), delimiter)
rowId = Join(Array(rng(1, 1).Value, rng(1, 2).Value, rng(1, 3).Value, rng(1, 4).Value, rng(1, 5).Value, rng(1, 6).Value, rng(1, 7).Value, rng(1, 8).Value, rng(1, 9).Value), delimiter)
```

Then `rowId` for **1st** row looks like this:

```
LU3707-E01#;#Blending_1#;##;##;#1#;#Blending#;#True#;##;#
```

Then `rowId` for **2nd** row looks like this:

```
LU3707-E01#;#Screening milling_2#;##;##;#2#;#Screening Milling#;#True#;#LU3707-E01#;#Blending_1
```

Then `rowId` for **3rd** row looks like this:

```
LU3707-E01#;#Blending_3#;##;##;#3#;#Blending#;#True#;#LU3707-E01#;#Screening milling_2
```

So it looks like table's indexes somehow got mixed and `rng(1, 7)` actually targets column *"Ignore Validation"* *(the last column)*.

How is this possible? Is it possible that table was created and then someone moved the "Ignore Validation" column to the right side of the table? How can this be done? I would like to know, because I would like to move it back.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible to have the shown strings return from the picture you show... Please, show us how you call the function, and previously check if you call the function with the rows **you think** they are...

Comment: You have posted an unrelated screenshot or you're applying the function to the wrong table.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am 100% sure that this is correct image. I figured out that indexes somehow got mixed and `rng(1, 7)` actually targets column *"Ignore Validation"* *(the last column)*. How is this possible? Is it possible that table was created and then someone moved the *"Ignore Validation"* column to the right side of the table? How can this be done? I would like to know, because I would like to move it back.

Comment: Do you show us the whole involved row? Since in the string the first element on the first row is "LU3707-B" and in picture is "LU3707-E01", how to be the correct pair picture/string? Forget about "Ignore Validation" now. Is this column formatted as `Boolean`? But this is something else...

Comment: @FaneDuru I am sorry I really posted wrong image. Fixed.

Comment: I found a solution. The problem was that there was a **hidden** column there!

Comment: This is not really as "solution"... This is only an explanation of what your code returns. I had in mind such a possibility, but to return a different string in the first column was ove my understanding capability... Anyhow, it is good you understood where the problem was.

Comment: Maybe better solution would be to reference columns like [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/vb/excel+vba+get+table+column+index+by+name).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. The problem was that column `J` was hidden. I later found out that also column `M` was hidden. Problem is that these hidden columns have a really barely noticeable indicator marked in the image:

[image]